# MS EXCEL | Find and Replace | Multiple Values at once | All worksheets at once

Tags: excel, vba, search, replace

I want to replace multiple values in an Excel workbook with multiple worksheets all at once. See screenshots:

- [Multiple Find and Replace Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVGw6.png)
- [Sheet for replacement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8qTw.png)
- [Sheet for replacement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jx43i.png)
- [Sheet for replacement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNula.png)

I also want the color in background of the cell to be copied from "Multiple Find and Replace Table" for replacement.

I found this VBA code,

```vb
Sub MultiFindNReplace()
    'Updateby Extendoffice
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim InputRng As Range, ReplaceRng As Range

    xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"

    Set InputRng = Application.Selection
    Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Original Range ", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
    Set ReplaceRng = Application.InputBox("Replace Range :", xTitleId, Type:=8)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each Rng In ReplaceRng.Columns(1).Cells
        InputRng.Replace what:=Rng.Value, replacement:=Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

But it only works for selection on one worksheet. Is there a way to do it for multiple selected worksheets or the whole workbook?

Comment: Please, do not use links to other pages. Edit your question and post here the code you say that works for one sheet and I will show you how to use it for all existing. You may make a note saying where from the code has been taken.

Comment: I have quoted the code snippet.

Comment: Do you have „Kutools” installed? Did you test this code for one sheet and does it work?

Comment: No need to install Kutools for this script. I just added a module to my macros and a shortcut to the macro. It worked like a charm on the selection.

Comment: Yes, I did not look to it after seeing their 'sign'... So, how do you like the adapted code to behave? You will select two specific ranges on a sheet and do you want the code to process the same ranges in all existing sheets? Or you want the code to ask for each sheet about its specific ranges to be processed?

Comment: I want the code to ask for each sheet about its specific ranges to be processed.
Also the replacement should follow the formatting of source.

Is it possible to automate it without manually selecting for each sheet? Like can we decide we have to select (say column C ) or each sheet present in workbook?

Comment: I cannot get you, sorry... What do you mean by "formatting of source"? The cells format? If yes, `Repace` works only on cells values. Now, do you need to replace part of the cell string, or all the value? In this last case, the code must be adapted. I mean to copy - paste instead of replacing. And it can copy the format, too. But you must tell us what you need. Please, think about it and state what is to be done. About your last (unclear) question, if I correctly understood it, the answer is yes, but it means that you will not "ask for each sheet" as you say. This request makes no sense, so...

Comment: Did you clarify what you really need? I will leave my office for some time, after some minutes...

Comment: I have edited the question with pictures, for what I want.

Comment: So, let me express what I understood and confirm if it is correct. If not, please better explain what you try accomplishing. 1) Your code will start from sheet "Multiple Find and Replace Table". 2) The dates in column B:B of the active sheet should be copied and replace all the values in column A:A of the other sheets. Is this understanding correct? If yes, is the the number of rows in each sheet  the same?

Comment: Yes, perfectly understood. Additionally if possible also the cell format of each cell in column B:B (I noticed replace can not do it, any other workaround, if possible.)
No the number of rows is not same and also there could be blank cells in between.

Comment: So, you simply want replacing the existing cell values in A:A columns of all existing sheets, with the one existing in B:B column of the active sheet ("Multiple Find and Replace Table"). Is its real name "Sheet1", as I can see in the picture?

Comment: Yes, I can manage the sheet name once a working solution is available for this case.

Comment: Then, your code is useless... I will prepare a piece of code in two, three minutes.

Comment: Thanks @FaneDuru that will be wonderful.

Comment: Didn't you find some time to test the code I posted? If tested, didn't it do what you need? If not, please explain what do you need against it does...

Answer (score 0):

Please, test the next code. You should adapt the active sheet, or using the test workbook let "Sheet1" to be the one where the column B:B values to be copied from:

```
Sub testReplaceValuesAllSheets()
 Dim ash As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rngC As Range
 
 Set ash = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'use here the sheet with the column to replace the others
 lastR = ash.Range("B" & ash.Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 Set rngC = ash.Range("B2:B" & lastR): rngC.Copy
 
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    ws.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
 Next
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

The above code will also replace the column A:A cells value. If you need to be excepted, I can adapt the code to do it.

Please, test it and send some feedback.